# Quarkus not return data and I need interrupt manually the call when I call Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, quarkus

Thanks a lot for the opportunity.

I'm trying to call a Oracle Stored Procedure at Quarkus app, but when I try,the REST call break and not return data.

In my code, I have others resources that realize direct SELECT at the same database and to return normally data for me.

But when I try to call this Stored Procedure, this call stay in loop and not response data for me.

quarkus version: 2.1.1.Final
Oracle Database: 9.2.0.1

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I Use AgroalDatasource.

Some arguments of my application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.ORACLEDB.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.ORACLEDB.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource.ORACLEDB.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/SOMENAME
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver
quarkus.datasource.ORACLEDB.username=xxxxxx
quarkus.datasource.ORACLEDB.password=qqqqqqqqq
```

Thanks a lot,

Logs DEBUG:

````
669 DEBUG [io.net.uti.Recycler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
DEBUG [io.net.uti.Recycler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
DEBUG [io.net.uti.Recycler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
DEBUG [io.net.uti.Recycler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
DEBUG [io.net.uti.Recycler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.recycler.delayedQueue.ratio: 8
DEBUG [io.net.buf.AbstractByteBuf] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
DEBUG [io.net.buf.AbstractByteBuf] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
DEBUG [io.net.uti.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@7efd258e
DEBUG [io.net.han.cod.com.ZlibCodecFactory] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.noJdkZlibDecoder: false
DEBUG [io.net.han.cod.com.ZlibCodecFactory] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) -Dio.netty.noJdkZlibEncoder: false
DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) requestBegin {CONNECTED_SOCKET_SAMPLE=io.micrometer.core.instrument.composite.CompositeLongTaskTimer$CompositeSample@72441d9c}, HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@6c14f5c5]
DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@6c14f5c5]
DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@6c14f5c5]
DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@6c14f5c5]
DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) requestRouted / HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@6c14f5c5]
DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-0) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77
DEBUG [io.sma.fau.cor.eve.loop] (executor-thread-0) No event loop integration found

After Error: socket hang up at the Client. This erro was after I interromp the Quarkus because did already more than 30 minutes the connection.

817 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) requestReset HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/access/facilidade/11111/2222/3333/55/77, currentRoutePath=/, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@6c14f5c5]
842 DEBUG [io.qua.resteasy] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) IO Exception : io.vertx.core.VertxException: Connection was closed```
````

Follow my code:

Controller Class:

```
@GET
@Path("/facilidade/{id}/{cep}/{servico}/{os}/{tipo}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput> confirmaFacilidadeCompleta(
        @PathParam(value="id") Long id, 
        @PathParam(value="cep") String cep, 
        @PathParam(value="servico") String servico, 
        @PathParam(value="os") String os,
        @PathParam(value="tipo") Long tipo)
                
{
    List<ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput> confirmaFacilidadeCompleta = (List<ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput>)                                 service.confirmaFacilidadeCompletaService(id,cep,servico,os,tipo);
    return confirmaFacilidadeCompleta;
}
```

```
DAO Class:

    @Inject
    @Named("ORACLEDB")
    AgroalDataSource dataSource;


    public List<ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput> confirmaFacilidadeCompletaDAO(Long id, String cep, String servico, String os,
            Long tipo) 
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

        try 
        {
            
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call OWNER.PKG_CONFIRM(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) } ");
            
            try
            {
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
                
                callableStatement.setLong(2,id);
                callableStatement.setString(3, cep);
                callableStatement.setString(4, servico);
                callableStatement.setString(5, os);
                callableStatement.setLong(6, tipo);
                callableStatement.setString(7, null);
                callableStatement.setString(8, null);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(9, Types.VARCHAR);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(10,Types.VARCHAR);
                
                callableStatement.execute();
                logger.info("Procedure ou Function executada com sucesso.");

                List<ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput> outPut = new ArrayList<ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput>();
                
                ((ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput) outPut).setRetornoFuncao(callableStatement.getInt(1));
                ((ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput) outPut).setVrRetorno(callableStatement.getString(9));
                ((ConfirmaFacilidadeCompletaOutput) outPut).setCodRetorno(callableStatement.getString(10));
            
                return outPut;
            }
            
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
    
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
    
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is there some code? Any debug logs?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for response. I added logs in the question.

Comment: how are you invoking your stored procedure ? and remember this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I put the code in the question. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: ojdbc14 is a very old JDBC driver, can you use the latest? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Comment: Hi Nirmala I tried but appeared the same error. My database is 9.2.0.1(9i). Thanks a lot.